# Missing percentage with LIME, how to improve the interpretation of LIME

Tags: python, bert-language-model, lime

Creating one script using LIME on text interpretation, it is possible don't have percentages?
In other hand, I have this script where "df['text']' is the dataset with several tweets text and each tweet has been classified, considering 0 or 1:

```
model = tf.saved_model.load('cnn_bert/', tags=["serve"]) # the model name is "saved_model.pb"
def predict_fn(texts):
predictions = model(texts, training=False) #texts is the tweet text pre-elaborated
return predictions.numpy()
```

LIME

```
class_names=['0','1']
explainer = LimeTextExplainer(class_names=class_names)
exp = explainer.explain_instance(df['text'][4587],predict_fn, num_features=5, num_samples=10)
exp.show_in_notebook(text=df['text'][4587])
```

Below there is the result, but no percentage (in particular on the second plot) has been shown, maybe there is some error in my script.
[image: reference image]